# Render different PartialViews onclick of different buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a view which is supposed to show three different things depending on what button you click, aka what you are sorting after. At the moment, it's static, and the buttons don't anything. So, I have a main view called "Order", and in this View I want to render the partial views PartialOrderZero, PartialOrderQuantity and PartialOrders.

At the moment what I've got working is, inside my Order.cshtml:

```
<div class="orderListing">
    @{Html.RenderAction("PartialQuantityZero");}
</div>
```

This works well, and I'm showing the data from my PartialView `OrdersQuantityZero`. Now, my goal is, onclick of different buttons, say `button1`, `button2` and `button3`, render my three different PartialViews. It seems like it should be done through jQuery but the syntax I've tried doesn't work. Is there any way to set a placeholder where `@{Html.RenderAction("PartialQuantityZero");}` is at the moment, and render the different views with a `$("#button1/2/3").click( function() { }`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use ajax to call a server method that returns a partial view and in its success callback, update the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#button').on('click',function(){
                $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {//data will be partial view
                $('.orderListing').html(data)
                }
            });
})
```

Comment: Thanks. So `url` will be url to my PartialView ActionResult in my Controller?

Comment: yes .. it will be .. have different divs with ids if u are going to make multiple calls

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you!